# Getting the next top date (MAX) without group by

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table with data with varting effective dates.

```
ProjectID | Proj_Start_DT | Proj_End_DT | Effective_DT 
A| 01-03-2013 |  31-12-2013 | 31-01-2013
**A| 01-03-2013 |  31-12-2013 | 28-02-2013**
A| 01-03-2013 |  31-12-2013 | 31-03-2013
A| 01-03-2013 |  31-12-2013 | 31-04-2013
```

How do I get the greatest Effective_DT that is less than the Proj_Start_DT and set it to be the Proj_Start_DT, leaving the rest of the records intact as it is without a group by clause?

From the above, the greatest Effective_DT that is less than Proj_Start_DT is the second record with 28-02-2013 (highlighted in bold). I will like to set it to 01-03-2013.

**EDIT:**
Just to add more info, the requirements is such that this has to be done in a single query(SELECT) instead of breaking down to chunk of program codes to do the processing. I am starting to look into analytics sql. Meanwhile, does anybody has any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Correlated sub-query for the max?

Comment: Do you want an `update` or `select` ?

Comment: I need a SELECT query instead of UPDATE @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 0):

You can update the table:

```
update table t
    set effective_dt = proj_start_dt
    where t.effective_dt = (select max(t2.effective_dt)
                            from table t2
                            where t2.projectId = t.projectId and
                                  t2.effective_dt < t.proj_start_dt
                           );
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try the following:

```
UPDATE projects p
   SET p.effective_dt = p.proj_start_dt
 WHERE p.effective_dt < p.proj_start_dt
   AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM projects p2
                     WHERE p2.projectID = p.projectID
                       AND p2.effective_dt > p.effective_dt
                       AND p2.effective_dt < p2.proj_start_dt );
```

In other words, update `effective_dt` to be `proj_start_dt` where the former is less than the latter and where a greater value of `effective_dt`, also less than `proj_start_dt`, doesn't exist.